# Is there a way to access winecfg options from the terminal?

Tags: scripts, wine

I am trying to set up a script that sets up WINE for you and installs what you want from a selection of programs. Is it possible to toggle options within winecfg from the terminal? Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. 
winecfg is a gui editor of some settings in the registry.

You would have to write your script to edit the registry files within the ~/.wine folder.

Comment: OK. I thought that was most likely the case, but couldn't find anything saying whether or not it was. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Good luck.